# Could the SO notifications be a bit cleaner?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, notification-bar

I'm not sure what to call them, but I'm talking about the bars that appear on the top of the screen when you earn a new badge, and things like that.

When you have one bar, it's okay; it just fades out and the whole document slides up. When you have three or more bars (associating with another account gives you a ton of these), the bars don't go away as easily; they jerk, disappear too quickly, and things like that.

It would look more aesthetically pleasing if the bars were to both fade out and slide out at the same time, as that would make the whole layout a lot more professional and clean (don't worry, SO is just about the most beautiful site I've ever seen. It's so simple!).

Just an idea...

Comment: Don't worry, [no one knows what to call them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51176/messages-notifications-warnings-are-they-different-or-all-the-same-which-one).